# Append a placeholder value to a list wherever a value is not present in a table

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Basically my tables have a field called **EOS** with four possible values. I dissolve my table on the EOS field, and what I need to do now is append the EOS values to a list. The tricky part is that I want to append a value to the list for each possible EOS value, whether or not the value exists in the table.

So if my table looks like this:

```
EOS       Shape Length  
  1           56.7777  
  3           9589.88
```

This is how I need the list to output:

```
EOS_list = ['56.777', **'0'**, 9589.88', **'0'**]
```

I can't figure out how to append a zero value to the list where a value does not exist without getting things tangled up.

```
workspace = "C:\MyDocuments\Documents\Update.gdb"
testing = r"C:\MyDocuments\Documents\Update.gdb\Dissolve"
arcpy.env.workspace = testing
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fields = ["EOS", "Shape_Length"]
EOS_list = []
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Dissolve_EOS", fields)
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("Dissolve_EOS", "fc_EOS")
for f1, f2 in cursor:
    print f1
    print f2
    if arcpy.Exists(f1) and f1 == "1":
        EOS_list.append(f2)
        print EOS    
    elif arcpy.Exists(f1) and f1 == "2":
        EOS_list.append(f2)
    elif arcpy.Exists(f1) and f1 == "3":
        EOS_list.append(f2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arcpy.Exists` tells you if a *dataset* exists somewhere.

Starting with a dictionary of default values, you could update the dictionary where a value exists in your table, then create the output list in the order you need:

```
# set up some default values
EOS_vals = {
    '1': '0',
    '2': '0',
    '3': '0',
    '4': '0'
}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Dissolve_EOS", fields) as cursor:
    for f1, f2 in cursor:
        # update the defaults if there's a value in the table
        EOS_vals[f1] = f2
# build the output list
EOS_list = [EOS_vals['1'], EOS_vals['2'], EOS_vals['3'], EOS_vals['4']]
```

You show the list as strings but length fields are usually numbers, so you may want to use `0` instead of `'0'`.

Comment: This is helpful, but not exactly what I am looking to do. The table may have all value options, or it may have a combination of the four. The zeros need to be placeholders in the list. 

The list needs to append the value in a certain order, and leave a placeholder if a value does not exist. Such as, if the table had a value for 1, 2, and 4, there would need to be a zero at the second place in the list.   

  
EOS_list = [value for 1, value for 2, value for 3, value for 4 ]   
  
Since no value exists for 2, I need to append a zero to the list in that specific spot.

Comment: Updated to preserve order.

Comment: That worked great, thank you so much. Do you mind telling me what the EOS_vals defualt values thing that you set-up is called in Python? I'm still pretty novice, and I'm trying to learn more about new things when I encounter them

Comment: In Python that's a 'dictionary', it stores key:value pairs.